# Error Missing required argument $authorizationChecks in Login admin after upgrading from magento 2.4.0 to 2.4.3

Tags: admin-panel, admin-login

I can't access the magento 2 admin panel after upgrading from version 2.4.0 to version 2.4.3.
I have followed all the steps and cleared all the caches but I can't get in.
Instead, the frontend works fine.

Error is: `(BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $authorizationChecks of Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\AuthorizationComposite`

I attach a screenshot of the error.

Thank you all!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to disable `Magefan_Community` module and check if the issue is resolved.
2. If the issue persists, try to disable `Bss_CustomOptionAbsolutePriceQuantity` module and  check if the issue is resolved.
3. If the issue persists, run the following command to find which module call `AuthorizationComposite` class

```
grep -r AuthorizationComposite app vendor
```

then add the result to your question. I'll continue help you to fix
this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> **Please disable the Bss_CustomOptionAbsolutePriceQuantity module and run the di compile command.**

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:d:c
```

**Error is saying you have an invalid sequence in conductor params, please follow the same sequence from a parent class and variable with values are placed last. like $data, $arrayVar = [], etc.**